# Rotation versus transform.forward in Unity

Tags: unity

I want my player to "face" the direction they're moving, or if not moving, face the last movement direction. There are two solutions I see most often, using rotation (usually `Transform.LookAt`) or a "forward" vector, `transform.forward`.

Is there a reason to use one or the other? What do I gain/lose by using one over the other?

For the time being I'm updating `transform.forward` with a normalized vector of my character movement, unless it's 0,0. That doesn't work 100% so I have some logic left, but I want to understand why this isn't done using rotation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Use `Transform.LookAt()`

I didn't even realize that Transform.forward was even *assignable* until I peeked at the documentation just now, but even so I wouldn't do that; it feels improper.

`Transform.LookAt()` will be more reliable, as it should be able to handle a 0,0 vector more easily, just make sure to add the movement vector *to* the player position vector before passing it into `LookAt()` or your player will always look towards scene origin!

Comment: I didn't know that was possible either. It just feels dirty.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should use [`Quaternion.LookRotation`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.LookRotation.html), simply passing in your velocity vector as the “forward” argument, and then just assign that to `transform.rotation`. Slightly less maths involved overall, and at least for me it would be conceptually easier to parse. You don’t have to worry about offsetting to a point in space or anything.